# How to countif 56 exists in 156/56/2567 and only return true once? Google sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, countif

I have one sheet with data on my facebook ads. I have another sheet with data on the products in my store. I'm having trouble with some countifs where I'm counting how many times my product ID exists in a row where multiple numbers are. They are formatted like this: /2032/2034/2040/1/

It's easy on the rows where only one product ID exists but some rows have multiple ID's separated by a /. And I need to see if the ID exists as a exact match alone or somewhere between the /'s.

```
Rows with facebook ads data:
A1: /2032/2034/2040/1/
A2: /1548/84/2154/2001/
A3: /2032/1689/1840/2548/

Row with product data:
B1: 2034
C1: I need a countifs here that checks how many times B1 exists in column A. Lets say I have thousands of rows with different variations of A1 where B1 could standalone. How do I count this? I always need exact matches.
```

Comment: `(?:^|/)56(?:/|$)` would do it.

Comment: Do you want to check if the 56 is alone or if it exists inside another number like 156?

Comment: @Kessy I want to check if it exists alone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the number you want (56) with the REGEX @MonkeyZeus commented whith a little change -> `"(?:^|/)"&B1&"(?:/|$)"` so the end result is:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1, "(?:^|/)"&B1&"(?:/|$)"), true, false)
```

Example:

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

If you need to count the total of 56 in X rows you can change the "True / False" of the condition for "1 / 0" and then do a `=SUM(C1:C5)` on the last row:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1, "(?:^|/)"&B1&"(?:/|$)"), 1, 0)
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2**

> Thanks for contributing. Unfortunately I'm not able to do it this way
>   since I have loads of data to do this on. Is there a way to do it with
>   a countif in a single cell without adding a extra step with "sum"?

In that case you can do:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A:A,  REGEXMATCH(A:A,  "(?:^|/)"&B2&"(?:/|$)")))
```

Example:

[image]

---

**UPDATE 3**

With the following condition you check every single possibility just by adding another **COUNTIF**:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,B1) + COUNTIF(A:A, "*/"&B1) + COUNTIF(A:A, B1&"/*") + COUNTIF(A:A, "*/"&B1&"/*")
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, how do I complete this with a countifs? Let's say I have multiple rows and I want to check how many times 56 stands alone.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Unfortunately I'm not able to do it this way since I have loads of data to do this on. Is there a way to do it with a countif in a single cell without adding a extra step with "sum"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't realize I have to write down all the data to account for. In the column A there could also be rows consisting of single numbers, like: "55". In the count I would also need to have a conditions, like if a cell in another column on the same row contain certain text. Is this doable? This is the data I'm "counting" from: https://imgur.com/a/47UIqAO

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=COUNTIF(SPLIT(A1, "/"), B1)
```

[image: 0]

---

### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2<>"", {
 SUM(IF((REGEXMATCH(""&DATA!C:C, ""&A2))*(DATA!B:B="carousel"),  1, )), 
 SUM(IF((REGEXMATCH(""&DATA!C:C, ""&A2))*(DATA!B:B="imagepost"), 1, ))}, ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks, how do I modify this if I have multiple values in column A and what to see if 56 exists in multiple rows?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with some example?

Comment: here is a copy of the sheet. I want to count how many times the product with id 1995 exist as a carousel ad and imagepost ad. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12l6wpUn76G2iwUkuMks8IceHCoeP0iuS-LEUkkpyDzY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for the help. Could you have another look at the sheet? What if I want to account for which country the ad is running in? I've removed the imagepost column and added another country parameter, also a column for countries in the ADZ page.

Comment: Hi again and thanks for the help. Unfortunately, it doesn't work 100% correct. If I have a product with id 50, it gives this product a count in an id that is for example 501, so it doesn't count exact matches only.

Comment: @MarcusPedersen see your sheet now - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp9Vq.png